# Installing composer in a docker container

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, protocol-buffers

I'm using docker for a small PHP server where I built the image FROM tutum/lamp:latest. I'm need to use [protocol buffers](https://github.com/protobuf-php/protobuf) and for that I first need to install composer.

I'm trying to install it by doing the following:

`docker pull composer/composer`

`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer install`

I have the files, including composer.json located in `/app` and they are moved there from my host machine each time I start the image. However, I still get the error that `composer can't find a file composer.json in /app` which is quite annoying. I used [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/) as a guide.

Comment: What is your native OS ? Linux, macOS, Windows ?

Comment: Its Linux @b.enoit.be

Comment: End when you run your docker command are you 100% sure that you run it from the folder where your `composer.json` is ?

Comment: nope, i have a script to launch it, i cant run `docker run .... ` inside the image can I? I only have php in the image, not even docker.. so basically i run the docker command before even getting to the directories. @b.enoit.be

Comment: Wait, what ? `-v $(pwd):/app` is actually mounting a volume for docker. It basically means that the actual folder from where you run your command (`docker run...`) is going to be mounted in the container in the `/app` folder. So in short that means that your `composer.json` have to lie in the folder from where your run the command (`docker run...`)

Comment: Yes, composer.json is in the /app folder, but that is just a folder, its not a container or anything.. do i need to do anything extra for it? make it a volume or anything?

Comment: @b.enoit.be here

Answer (score 1):

The `/app` part of the Composer command is unrelated to the actual path your application files are in.

While in the host (not inside any container), you just have to **change your current directory** to your application directory where the `composer.json` resides, and then run that given command as is (whatever the actual path of your app files).

Or, seeing as `composer/composer` container is deprecated, this would be a better command: `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app composer install` ([from here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/composer/)).

Answer (score 0):

**./docker/Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2-zts-alpine3.17
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN apk add bash
```

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:

    php8.2-template:
        build:
            context: "./docker"
        working_dir: "/application"
        volumes:
            - "./:/application"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        command: "php -S 0.0.0.0:80 /application/src/server.php"
```